# When should i create mysql trigger?

Tags: mysql, triggers

Are triggers specifics to each mysql connection? Or is it done when i create trigger one time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A [trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html) is created on a table, not on a connection, and once defined it remains on the table until it is explicitly [dropped](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/drop-trigger.html). It can be defined to fire for INSERT, UPDATE and/or DELETE operations on the given table.